# Does Microsoft Rpc stub head file need Compiler Upgrade?

Tags: visual-c++, rpc, midl

I have upgrade the VS compiler of the whole product, but use the old .h and .c for RPC compiled by the old MIDL compiler, it seems work well, but will it bring problems for adaptation?

I have test most of the request on test environment.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.